# How to convert string datetime to string using SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

In input I have a string datetime (yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS), how can I convert it to HH:MI:SS dd/mm/yyyy in output?

Comment: output also must be in string

Comment: Please clarify, as this is often a point of confusion.  What is the actual _data type_ of your "string datetime"?  is it really a 'string" (varchar or varchar2) or is it of datatype DATE? If it is DATE, then you would use @Gordon Linoff answer.  If it is truely a string, then you would simply use SUBSTR.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your `string --> date --> string` to achieve it as follows:

```
 -- consider, your string is - '2020-06-05 17:48:00'

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(
  2  TO_DATE('2020-06-05 17:48:00',
  3  'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'),
  4  'HH24:MI:SS dd/mm/yyyy'
  5  ) AS RES
  6    FROM DUAL;

RES
-------------------
17:48:00 05/06/2020

SQL>
```

Comment: if the input truly is a string, then there is no need to convert it to a date, just to extract the "time" part of the string.  All it would need would be "substr('2020-06-05 17:48:00',12)"

Comment: But requirement is to format the date in different order.

Answer (score 0):

You use `to_char()`:

```
 select to_char(col, 'HH24:MI:SS DD/MM/YYYY')
```